# Extend Content Delivery Web Service (OData) - how far can it be taken?

Tags: content-delivery, odata

I've been playing with OData recently, and found a few (small) limitations on the out-of-the-box web service. I wonder if some of these limitations can be catered for by extending what is there already.

This question is purely exploratory: at this point in time I did not *try* anything yet.

Some of the things I want to explore:

- Provide support to read `SchemaContents` using the /Schemas collection (currently Schemas only expose Publication ID, Schema ID and Title)
- Create my own custom entities (for instance, "/Articles" which would map to "/Schemas(SchemaId=xx,PublicationId=xx)/Components")

Any tips/hints? Will it not work at all and I shouldn't bother? Probably better to create my own webservice on top of the current service and/or API?

Comment: I am also starting working on this direction, if anybody has contributed in this direction please suggest. Thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say both are technically possible, although for the additional data you may have to store the data on your own if it isn't already available. You could do so with a publisher extension.

It's definitely possible to create your own methods in the existing web service -- you just have to implement a couple of interfaces. We did that to expose Promotions from SmartTarget, for instance. We needed to implement ODataEntryRegistrationService, ResolverBase, PropertyWrapper, Entity/BaseEntity, and EntryBuilder -- all from the com.tridion.webservices.odata package.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any documentation about it -- which might indicate that it isn't yet a public extension mechanism (I don't know for sure either way).

Comment: Thanks Peter. It is probably internal indeed, but since I'm exploring only and this won't be used in any "real" project, I'm not afraid to go there! :)

Comment: please note that the 'interface' has changed in 2013, so looking at what SmartTarget did will get you only part of the way

Comment: and yes is it still internal api

Comment: The UGC product also extended the Odata web service and could possibly also be of help to you in this research.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way to extend the Odata.

Please check the referenced article: [Odata Extension](http://mihaiconsulting.com/projects/odata-query-extension)

Please note, extension is possible to odata however after every upgrade you might have to revisit this extension so that it continues to work.